# How to display only an array's 5 elements from a MongoDB collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

**Introduction**

I am trying to make a query that outputs only an array, and within that array outputs only 5 elements of that array. I've gotten them working individually but cannot get them to work together.

**Code**

Output only array in its entireity:

```
db.mycoll.find({
    "_id": ObjectId("5b55d0a34270ce58b8bfabcd"),     
    "myarr.platform": "9 and 3 quarters"
},{
    myarr: 1
}).pretty()
```

Output only 5 elements of array, but also displays other fields:

```
db.mycoll.find({
    "_id": ObjectId("5b55d0a34270ce58b8bfabcd"),     
    "myarr.platform": "9 and 3 quarters"
},{
    myarr:{ $slice: 5 }
}).pretty()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I believe my question is independant of any specific collection. Is there any particular detail you're looking for?

Comment: db.mycoll.find({"_id": ObjectId("5b55d0a34270ce58b8bfabcd"), "myarr.platform": "9 and 3 quarters"}, myarr:{ $slice: 5 }, {myarr: 1}).pretty()

Comment: @YuTse that throws a syntax error: ```SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):1:105```

Comment: db.mycoll.find({"_id": ObjectId("5b55d0a34270ce58b8bfabcd"), "myarr.platform": "9 and 3 quarters"}, {myarr:{ $slice: 5 }}, {myarr: 1}).pretty()

Comment: @YuTse That also doesn't work since the ```find``` function has only two parameters, and you've added two projections instead of one. FYI putting curly braces around the two projections doesn't work as well. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by explicitly setting `_id: 1` in the projection. This uses the property of `find` that if any field is included in the projection, all other fields will be excluded, unless also explicitly included.

```
db.mycoll.find({
     "_id": ObjectId("5b55d0a34270ce58b8bfabcd"),     
     "myarr.platform": "9 and 3 quarters"
},{
    "myarr" : { $slice: 5 },
    "_id" : 1
}).pretty()
```

For more, read the note here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection